# Fix Renderbox Error with Horizontal Listview

Tags: flutter

I am trying to change my ListView to be Shown horizontally instead of veritcally by default. However, when  I have done this, I face the following an error. The error occurs at both the Widgets returned by the _buildListItem function and disappears when the scrolldirection is changed from vertical back to horizontal.

```
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPointerListener#98473 relayoutBoundary=up5 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
```

The code of the ListView Builder is

```
Widget _buildListItem (BuildContext context,DocumentSnapshot doc,int index)
{

if(index ==0)
  {
    return ListTile(title:Container( height:200,width: 100,child: Card(shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(),child:Column(children:<Widget>[new Flexible(child:Text(widget.prayerName,style: TextStyle(fontSize: 32,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))),Text(widget.blurb,style: TextStyle(fontSize: 28))]))));

  }

else {
  return RaisedButton(child: Text("a"),);





}
}
```

Here is the body of my build widget where my list view is declared

```
body: StreamBuilder(

 stream: Firestore.instance.collection('quranKhwani').document(widget.docID).collection("juz").orderBy("juzNumber").snapshots(),
 builder: (context,snapshot)
   {


     if(!snapshot.hasData)return const Text("Loading..");
     return ListView.builder(
       shrinkWrap: true,
       scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
       itemBuilder: (context,index)=>


       _buildListItem(context,snapshot.data.documents[index],index),
       itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                             );
   }
)
));
```

Comment: I think you need to add a parent height on your ListView.builder.. so maybe Container(height: 250, child: ListView.builder);

Comment: Nope, still the same error. It also throws up this error as well  ```[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: Cannot hit test a render box with no size.
E/flutter (17481): The hitTest() method was called on this RenderBox: RenderConstrainedBox#0d2ec relayoutBoundary=up1:
E/flutter (17481):   needs compositing```

Comment: i edited my post..Wrap your steambuilder with Container and add height

Comment: Still didn't work,sadly gives the same errors.

Answer (score 1):

```
  Container(
                      height: _height //add height
                      child: StreamBuilder(
                        builder: (context, snapshot) {
                          return ListView.builder(
                              itemBuilder: (context, index) {},
                              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                            );
                        },
                      ),
                    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to give height to the `StreamBuilder` like:

```
body: Container(
    height: 300,    // Height you want
    child: 
        StreamBuilder(
            stream: Firestore.instance.collection('quranKhwani').document(widget.docID).collection("juz").orderBy("juzNumber").snapshots(),
            builder: (context,snapshot)
            {


                if(!snapshot.hasData)return const Text("Loading..");
                return ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                itemBuilder: (context,index)=>


                _buildListItem(context,snapshot.data.documents[index],index),
                itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                                        );
            }
        ),
    ),
),
```

Comment: I also tried that but to no avail. The same errors still occur. Could this error be occuring because there is not enough space for the widgets?

Comment: I don't think so